# Moving an SVG with Vue

Tags: javascript, svg, vue.js

I am trying to implement a feature that will allow me to `mousedown` and drag SVG shapes. I have the basic functionality working, but I cannot figure out why after I drag the shape then perform `mouseup` event, when I attempt to drag the same shape again, the shape does not drag along with the mouse position. The shape remains stationary, and only when I do another `mouseup` will the shape start following the mouse position again.

Here is a mixin I wrote that extends moveable behavior:

```
const Moveable = {
    data () {
      return {
         x: '',
         y: '',
         coords: {
           x: 0,
           y: 0
         }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      handleMouseMove(e) {
        const xDiff = this.coords.x - e.pageX;
        const yDiff = this.coords.y - e.pageY;

        this.coords.x = e.pageX;
        this.coords.y = e.pageY;
        this.x = this.x - xDiff;
        this.y = this.y - yDiff;
      },
      handleMouseDown(e) {
        this.coords = {
          x: e.pageX,
          y: e.pageY
        };
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove);
      },
      handleMouseUp() {
        document.removeEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove);
       this.coords = {};
      }
    }
}
```

Here is demo that demonstrates the problem: https://codepen.io/p-adams/pen/gGwEQQ

Why is the shape only correctly dragging when it is first moved, and for subsequent drags, it does not immediately follow the mouse position?

Comment: did you fix it? seems like your codepen works perfectly (chrome)

Comment: also I would recommend to attach move and mouse up listeners on mouse down, and remove BOTH on mouse up

Comment: @SergeyRudenko seems like this only happens on FireFox! Works fine for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is because if you start dragging `first element` and mouseup on  `second element`, `second element`'s handleMouseUp is called( in fact `first element`'s mouseup should be called).

**Solution:**

You have to remove all event listener on mouse up.

Comment: well mousedown should be kept though, but the others (move, up) should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to store the element on mouse down, then you can remove the event handler for correct element on the mouse up.

```
let myElement = {}
const Moveable = {
  data () {
    return {
      x: '',
      y: '',
      coords: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }
    }
  },
//  myElement : Any,
  methods: {
    handleMouseMove(e) {
      const xDiff = this.coords.x - e.pageX;
      const yDiff = this.coords.y - e.pageY;

      this.coords.x = e.pageX;
      this.coords.y = e.pageY;
      this.x = this.x - xDiff;
      this.y = this.y - yDiff;
    },
    handleMouseDown(e) {
      this.coords = {
        x: e.pageX,
        y: e.pageY
      };
      myElement = this;
      document.addEventListener("mousemove", myElement.handleMouseMove);
    },
    handleMouseUp() {
      document.removeEventListener("mousemove", myElement.handleMouseMove);
      myElement.coords = {};
    }
  }
}
```